# How to create a random string using PHP?

Tags: php, string, random

I know that the rand function in PHP generates random integers, but what is the best way to generate a random string such as:

**Original string, 9 chars**

```
$string = 'abcdefghi';
```

**Example random string limiting to 6 chars**

```
$string = 'ibfeca';
```

UPDATE: I have found tons of these types of functions, basically I'm trying to understand the logic behind each step.

UPDATE: The function should generate any amount of chars as required.

Please comment the parts if you reply.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, exactly. The random string has to contain the letters from the original string? Can it only use each character once? What if you try to create a random string longer than the original?

Comment: Is this a 'write my code' question? What don't you understand about using random numbers that we may help you to learn?  It seems your algorithm is more specific than just generate any random string of length x.

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php/637322

Comment: @DForck42 - because it's not so random afterall. Compare: generate random string of length 32 with symbols [0-9a-f] and make for example md5(time()). In the second case, I could guess that "random" string in seconds (if I could easily check whether this random string is the used one), while really random string would take ages.

Comment: good question ! nearly all "random string" function just put out NUMBERS, not strings. until today i havent seen any one-line-string-only-random function

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Well, you didn't clarify all the questions I asked in my comment, but I'll assume that you want a function that can take a string of "possible" characters and a length of string to return. Commented thoroughly as requested, using more variables than I would normally, for clarity:

```
function get_random_string($valid_chars, $length)
{
    // start with an empty random string
    $random_string = "";

    // count the number of chars in the valid chars string so we know how many choices we have
    $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);

    // repeat the steps until we've created a string of the right length
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        // pick a random number from 1 up to the number of valid chars
        $random_pick = mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars);

        // take the random character out of the string of valid chars
        // subtract 1 from $random_pick because strings are indexed starting at 0, and we started picking at 1
        $random_char = $valid_chars[$random_pick-1];

        // add the randomly-chosen char onto the end of our string so far
        $random_string .= $random_char;
    }

    // return our finished random string
    return $random_string;
}
```

To call this function with your example data, you'd call it something like:

```
$original_string = 'abcdefghi';
$random_string = get_random_string($original_string, 6);
```

Note that this function doesn't check for uniqueness in the valid chars passed to it. For example, if you called it with a valid chars string of `'AAAB'`, it would be three times more likely to choose an A for each letter as a B. That could be considered a bug or a feature, depending on your needs.

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is unsafe as it relies upon `mt_rand()` which is [vulnerable to multiple attacks](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html)

Comment: @KeithDonegan Can you please un-accept this answer? It's incredibly insecure as ircmaxell points out. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29783745/2224584) is correct.

Answer (score 97):

If you want to allow repetitive occurences of characters, you can use this function:

```
function randString($length, $charset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789')
{
    $str = '';
    $count = strlen($charset);
    while ($length--) {
        $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $count-1)];
    }
    return $str;
}
```

The basic algorithm is to generate <*length*> times a random number between 0 and <*number of characters*> − 1 we use as index to pick a character from our set and concatenate those characters. The 0 and <*number of characters*> − 1 bounds represent the bounds of the `$charset` string as the first character is addressed with `$charset[0]` and the last with `$charset[count($charset) - 1]`.

Comment: Love this way, it's better than accepted solution, as simple as possible, but you should optimize it minimally by removing $count-1 from loop and putting it above: $count = strlen($charset) - 1;

Comment: Love this way as well! Very nice solution, am using it in preference of the accepted solution. The charset option makes it more useful too.

Comment: @s3m3n Read the accepted answer again. The code is the same, it just has more comments and uses more temporary variables :)

Comment: **WARNING**: This code is unsafe as it relies upon `mt_rand()` which is [vulnerable to multiple attacks](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html)

Answer (score 52):

My favorite:

```
 echo substr(md5(rand()), 0, 7);
```

Comment: Are you sure about the random properties of the first 7 characters of a md5 hash when hashing integers converted to strings? I think there's too many factors involved in your code if you need a good random distribution.

Comment: OK, it's not good enough for the machines in Las Vegas casino, but good enough to generate the registration key(eg.), which is active 30 minutes on web sites.

Comment: +1 for the one line method, when one just need a simple random string without the NSA security protocols

Comment: This solution does not produce a string with capital letters. Only small letters and numbers. Moreover, if you want other non-alphanumeric values in your string, then this would not generate them.

Comment: A nice one-liner, but using it has the danger of getting a false impression that the randomness of the generated string is any close to a truly random string of the same length.
Note that rand() can have a max value as low as 32767 (in case of PHP on windows) which means there will be just 32767 possible strings generated by this function, making it very prone to brute force attacks.

Answer (score 24):

So, let me start off by saying **USE A LIBRARY**. Many exist:

- [RandomCompat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/random_compat)
- [RandomLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/randomlib)
- [SecurityMultiTool](https://github.com/padraic/SecurityMultiTool)

The core of the problem is almost every answer in this page is susceptible to attack. `mt_rand()`, `rand()`, `lcg_value()` and `uniqid()` are all [vulnerable to attack](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html#attacking-php-s-random-number-generators).

A good system will use `/dev/urandom` from the filesystem, or `mcrypt_create_iv()` (with `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM`) or `openssl_pseudo_random_bytes()`. Which all of the above do. PHP 7 [will come with two new functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/easy_userland_csprng) `random_bytes($len)` and `random_int($min, $max)` that are also safe.

Be aware that most of those functions (except `random_int()`) return "raw strings" meaning they can contain any ASCII character from `0 - 255`. If you want a printable string, I'd suggest running the result through `base64_encode()`.

Comment: what is the php 7 way of randomness?

Answer (score 18):

```
function generate_random_string($name_length = 8) {
    $alpha_numeric = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($alpha_numeric, $name_length)), 0, $name_length);
}
```

Updated the code as per [mzhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873865/mzhang)'s great suggestion in the comments below.

Comment: "UPDATE: The function should generate any amount of chars as required." -- this function will max out at length 62.

Comment: Additionally, it's not random - there can only be one of each character in the resulting string with this approach. A truly random algorithm would have the *possibility* of resulting in 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', however unlikely.

Comment: thats scope creep, im calling shenanigans!

Comment: This is probably the best near-one-liner for generating random strings i have ever seen.

Comment: I really like this solution, but I can address @ChadBirch and @ceejayoz's issues - instead of `str_shuffle($alpha_numeric)`, just use `str_shuffle(str_repeat($alpha_numeric, $name_length))`; `str_repeat` generates a string which is repeated `n` times - this allows for `n` instances of each letter in the unshuffled string, allowing for the possibility of 'AAAA...' as final output.

Answer (score 9):

**A better and updated version of @taskamiski's excellent answer:**

Better version, using `mt_rand()` instead of `rand()`:

```
echo md5(mt_rand()); // 32 char string = 128bit
```

Even better, for longer strings, using the `hash()` function that allows to select hashing algorithmns:

```
echo hash('sha256', mt_rand()); // 64 char string
echo hash('sha512', mt_rand()); // 128 char string
```

If you want to cut the result down to let's say 50 chars, do it like this:

```
echo substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand()), 0, 50); // 50 char string
```

Comment: Simple and elegant! Other good option is `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)) // 32 char string`

Answer (score 6):

Joining characters at the end should be more efficient that repeated string concatenation.

Edit #1: Added option to avoid character repetition.

Edit #2: Throws exception to avoid getting into infinite loop if $norepeat is selected and $len is greater than the charset to pick from.

Edit #3: Uses array keys to store picked random characters when $norepeat is selected, as associative array key lookup is faster than linearly searching the array.

```
function rand_str($len, $norepeat = true)
{
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $max = strlen($chars) - 1;

    if ($norepeat && len > $max + 1) {
        throw new Exception("Non repetitive random string can't be longer than charset");
    }

    $rand_chars = array();

    while ($len) {
        $picked = $chars[mt_rand(0, $max)];

        if ($norepeat) {
            if (!array_key_exists($picked, $rand_chars)) {
                $rand_chars[$picked] = true;
                $len--;
            }
        }
        else {
            $rand_chars[] = $picked;
            $len--;
        }
    }

    return implode('', $norepeat ? array_keys($rand_chars) : $rand_chars);   
}
```

Comment: For the no-repeating case, if you're concerned with efficiency, it'd probably be better to use array_splice() to take each picked char out of the $chars array as it's picked, instead of adding an array search on every iteration.

Comment: Another way to improve efficiency could be storing the picked random chars as array index, and then use array_key_exists to check for repeated character. Array key lookup should be more efficient than in_array(), which probably does linear search.

Comment: It would seem that concatenation is actually faster by 20%-30%. Here is some code you can test with: http://pastebin.com/5mUxdWVH

Comment: For the no repeat logic this would be much more simpler: `$c = str_split($chars); shuffle($c); return substr(implode('', $c), 0, $len);`.

Answer (score 4):

this will generate random string

```
function generateRandomString($length=10) {
    $original_string = array_merge(range(0,9), range('a','z'), range('A', 'Z'));
    $original_string = implode("", $original_string);
    return substr(str_shuffle($original_string), 0, $length);
}
echo generateRandomString(6);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I will add my contribution here as well.

```
function random_string($length) {
    $bytes_1 = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
    $hex_1 = bin2hex($bytes_1);
    $random_numbers = substr(sha1(rand()), 0, $length);
    $bytes_2 = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length);
    $hex_2 = bin2hex($bytes_2);
    $combined_chars = $hex_1 . $random_numbers . $hex_2;
    $chars_crypted = hash('sha512', $combined_chars);

    return $chars_crypted;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What do you need a random string for?

Is this going to be used for anything remotely analogous to a password?

If your random string requires *any* security properties at all, you should use PHP 7's `random_int()` function instead of all the insecure `mt_rand()` answers in this thread.

```
/**
 * Generate a random string
 * 
 * @link https://paragonie.com/b/JvICXzh_jhLyt4y3
 *
 * @param int $length - How long should our random string be?
 * @param string $charset - A string of all possible characters to choose from
 * @return string
 */
function random_str($length = 32, $charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
{
    // Type checks:
    if (!is_numeric($length)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'random_str - Argument 1 - expected an integer'
        );
    }
    if (!is_string($charset)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'random_str - Argument 2 - expected a string'
        );
    }

    if ($length < 1) {
        // Just return an empty string. Any value < 1 is meaningless.
        return '';
    }
    // This is the maximum index for all of the characters in the string $charset
    $charset_max = strlen($charset) - 1;
    if ($charset_max < 1) {
        // Avoid letting users do: random_str($int, 'a'); -> 'aaaaa...'
        throw new LogicException(
            'random_str - Argument 2 - expected a string at least 2 characters long'
        );
    }
    // Now that we have good data, this is the meat of our function:
    $random_str = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $r = random_int(0, $charset_max);
        $random_str .= $charset[$r];
    }
    return $random_str;
}
```

If you aren't on PHP 7 yet (which is probably the case, as it hasn't been released as of this writing), then you'll want [paragonie/random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat), which is a userland implementation of `random_bytes()` and `random_int()` for PHP 5 projects.

**For security contexts, *always* use `random_int()`, not `rand()`, `mt_rand()`, etc.** See [ircmaxell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29783745/2224584) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Most aspects of this have already been discussed, but i'd recommend a slight update:
If you are using this for retail usage, I would avoid the domain
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

and instead use:
ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTUVWXY3456789

Granted, you end up with far fewer characters, but it saves a great deal of hassle, as customers cannot mistake 0 for O, or 1 for l or 2 for Z.  Also, you can do an UPPER on the input and customers can then enter upper or lower case letters -- that is also sometimes confusing since they can look similar.

Comment: I'd leave most lowercase letters. And perhaps splice up a string made of "syllables" (or at least common letter combinations).

Answer (score 2):

built on top of https://stackoverflow.com/a/853898/533426

but with php 7 cryptographically secure random function and lower AND upper case alphabet

```
function random($length = 8){
            $valid_chars ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

            // start with an empty random string
            $random_string = "";

            // count the number of chars in the valid chars string so we know how many choices we have
            $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);

            // repeat the steps until we've created a string of the right length
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
            {
                // pick a random number from 1 up to the number of valid chars
                $random_pick = random_int(1, $num_valid_chars);

                // take the random character out of the string of valid chars
                // subtract 1 from $random_pick because strings are indexed starting at 0, and we started picking at 1
                $random_char = $valid_chars[$random_pick-1];

                // add the randomly-chosen char onto the end of our string so far
                $random_string .= $random_char;
            }

            // return our finished random string
            return $random_string;
    }

//example output XjdXHakZ, yBG8hpZG, L6jg4FpK
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// @author http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2012/07/19/better-random-numbers-in-php-using-devurandom/                                                
function devurandom_rand($min = 0, $max = 0x7FFFFFFF)
{
    $diff = $max - $min;
    if ($diff < 0 || $diff > 0x7FFFFFFF) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Bad range');
    }
    $bytes = mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    if ($bytes === false || strlen($bytes) != 4) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Unable to get 4 bytes');
    }
    $ary = unpack('Nint', $bytes);
    $val = $ary['int'] & 0x7FFFFFFF; // 32-bit safe                           
    $fp = (float) $val / 2147483647.0; // convert to [0,1]                          
    return round($fp * $diff) + $min;
}

function build_token($length = 60, $characters_map = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789') {
    $map_length = mb_strlen($characters_map)-1;
    $token = '';
    while ($length--) {
        $token .= mb_substr($characters_map, devurandom_rand(0,$map_length),1);
    }
    return $token;
}
```

This will work only in UNIX environment where PHP is compiled with `mcrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr(bin2hex(random_bytes(14)), 0, $length);
```

this code gets a random bytes, that are converted from binary to hexadecimal, and then takes a substring of this hexadecimal string, as long you puts in $length variable

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: What if $length is greater than 28? Also this will only use hex digits, severely limiting the entropy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the last thing this question needs is another answer, but I got tired of seeing every one of these answers with an `ABCDEFGHI...` string in them. Just use ASCII! (Also, we need more answers that aren't using `rand()` and `mt_rand()`.)

It's pretty straightforward, just generating a random ASCII code in a loop, optionally filtering for punctuation, and appending the character to a string. Implemented as a standalone class, this will only work in modern versions of PHP.

```php
class RandomString implements Stringable {
    const PRINTABLE_START = 0x33;
    const PRINTABLE_END = 0x7E;

    public function __construct(
        private int $length = 12,
        private bool $alphanumeric = true
    ){}

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        $ret = "";
        do {
            $cp = random_int(self::PRINTABLE_START, self::PRINTABLE_END);
            $ret .= ($this->alphanumeric && self::isPunctuation($cp)) ? "" : chr($cp);
        } while (strlen($ret) < $this->length);

        return $ret;
    }

    private static function isPunctuation(int $code): bool
    {
        return ($code < 0x30)
            || ($code > 0x39 && $code < 0x41)
            || ($code > 0x5A && $code < 0x61)
            || ($code > 0x7A);
    }
}

echo new RandomString();
echo new RandomString(alphanumeric: false);
echo new RandomString(16);
```

Output:

```
62jnmI2f8OhJ
qRXIjngt>cKO
c8k2znh0XN12aj9a
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to create your password by a random permutation of the original letters? Should it just contain unique characters?

Use `rand` to choose random letters by index.

Comment: Succinct, true. However he directly asked for people to NOT be succinct, because he's trying to understand the logic behind it.

Answer (score -1):

you could make an array of characters then use rand() to pick a letter from the array and added it to a string.

```
$letters = array( [0] => 'a' [1] => 'b' [2] => 'c' [3] => 'd' ... [25] = 'z');

$lengthOfString = 10;
$str = '';

while( $lengthOfString-- )
{
   $str .= $letters[rand(0,25)];
}
echo $str;
```

*note that this does allow repeat characters

Comment: Considering that rand() with no arguments returns a value between 0 and getrandmax(), this code is going to print out an empty string about 99.9% of the time, quite possibly more, depending on your platform. And never mind the way you used 27 lines of code to set up a 26-element array.

Comment: That isn't a valid way to declare an array, and you still have a 1/27 chance of picking a non-existent array element every time.

Answer (score -1):

This builds on [Gumbo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853870/404699) by adding functionality to list a set of characters to be skipped in the base character set.  The random string selects characters from `$base_charset` which do not also appear in `$skip_charset`.

```
/* Make a random string of length using characters from $charset, excluding $skip_chars.
 * @param length (integer) length of return value
 * @param skip_chars (string) characters to be excluded from $charset
 * @param charset (string) characters of posibilities for characters in return val
 * @return (string) random string of length $length    */
function rand_string(
        $length, 
        $skip_charset = '', 
        $base_charset='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'){
  $skip_len = strlen($skip_charset);
  for ($i = 0; $i<$skip_len; $i++){
    $base_charset = str_replace($skip_charset[$i], '', $base_charset);
  }
  cvar_dump($base_charset, '$base_charset after replace');
  $str = '';
  $count = strlen($base_charset);
  while ($length--) {
    $str .= $base_charset[mt_rand(0, $count - 1)];
  }
  return $str;
}
```

Here are some usage examples.  The first two examples use the default value for `$base_charset`.  The last example explicitly defines `$base_charset`.

```
echo rand_string(15, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
//  470620078953298
echo rand_string(8, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789');
//  UKLIHOTFSUZMFPU
echo rand_string(15, 'def', 'abcdef');
//  cbcbbccbabccaba
```

Comment: down voter, please state your reason for the downvote

Answer (score -1):

well, I was looking for a solution, and I kindda used @Chad Birch's solution merged with @Gumbo's one. This is what I came up with:

```
function get_random_string($length, $valid_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456790!·$%&/()=?¿¡',.-;:+*`+´ç")
{
    $random_string = "";
    $num_valid_chars = strlen($valid_chars);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++, $random_string .= $valid_chars[mt_rand(1, $num_valid_chars)-1]);
    return $random_string;
}
```

I think comments are pretty much unnecesary since the answers I used to build up this one are already thoroughly commented. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

If you're not concerned about time, memory, or cpu efficiency, and if your system can handle it, why not give this algorithm a try?!

```
function randStr($len, $charset = 'abcdABCD0123') {
    $out = '';
    $str = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; $i++) {
        $str[$i] = $charset;

        shuffle($str);
        $charset .= implode($charset, $str);
        $charset = str_shuffle($charset);
    }

    $str = array_flip($str);
    $str = array_keys($str);

    for ($i = 0; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; $i++) {
        shuffle($str);
    }

    $str = implode('', $str);

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
        $index = mt_rand(1, strlen($str));
        $out .= $str[$index - 1];
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < PHP_INT_MAX; $i++) {
        $out = str_shuffle($out);
    }

    return substr($out, 0, $len);
}
```

Maybe this will read better if it uses recursion, but I'm not sure if PHP uses tail recursion or not...

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but I want try to post my solution... I always use this my function to generate a custom random alphanumeric string...

```
<?php
  function random_alphanumeric($length) {
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345689';
    $my_string = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $pos = mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) -1);
      $my_string .= substr($chars, $pos, 1);
    }
    return $my_string;
  }
  $test = random_alphanumeric(50); // 50 characters
  echo $test;
?>
```

test: UFOruSSTCPIqxTRIIMTRkqjOGidcVlhYaS9gtwttxglheVugFM

if you need two or more unique strings you can use this trick...

```
$string_1 = random_alphanumeric(50);
$string_2 = random_alphanumeric(50);
while ($string_1 == $string_2) {
  $string_1 = random_alphanumeric(50);
  $string_2 = random_alphanumeric(50);
  if ($string_1 != $string_2) {
     break;
  }
}
echo $string_1;
echo "<br>\n";
echo $string_2;
```

$string_1: tMYicqLCHEvENwYbMUUVGTfkROxKIekEB2YXx5FHyVByp3mlJO

$string_2: XdMNJYpMlFRKFDlF6GhVn6jsBVNQ1BCCevj8yK2niFOgpDI2MU

I hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

Simple enough!

```
function RandomFromCharset($charset,$length) 
{

$characters = $charset; // your existing charset / defined string
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $random_from_charset = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
    {
        $random_from_charset.= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }

return random_from_charset;
}
```

Call the function as follows

```
RandomFromCharset($charset,$length);
```

where **$length** will be length of random string you want (this can be predefined also in the function as `RandomFromCharset(charset,$length=10)` ) to generate and **$charset** will be your existing string to which you want to restrict the characters.

Answer (score -1):

One approach is to generate an md5 from a random number and extract the number of characters you want:

```
<?php 
    $random = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 7);
    echo $random;
?>
```

`mt_rand` will generate a random number, `md5` will create a 32 character string (containing both letters and numbers) and, in this example, we're extracting the first 7 characters of text.

Comment: The people posting this kind of answer in 2010 had an excuse; you do not. Never use `mt_rand()`; it has been known to be insecure for years. As well, an MD5 checksum is only going to have 16 different characters in it.