# generate random number with php and then submit to database

Tags: php

I was wondering how to generate a random 9 digit number with php after a html form submit.

in english:

I have a form on my site....which posts data to a database. I would like to add another function to the php file that will generate a number for every form submit (something like a unique id number for every user that submits the form)

I can do all the database stuff. Just need to know how to generate the number.

Comment: If you want full control over the digits and length:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php

Comment: Instead of a random ID use an Autoincrementing Primary Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel? I recommend you have your database create a unique id via [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid).

Comment: could i later on select a row from a table in my database with this unique id?

Answer (score 2):

```
rand() = Max 32768 on windows machines
```

so if you choose to use:

```
mt_rand (100000000,999999999);
```

but i suggest you use the AI id from the database and pad it if your curtain you need length 9

```
str_pad(mysql_insert_id(), 9, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
000000001
000000002
000000003
...
000000199
and so on
```

Comment: so this would generate a unique number each time? (no duplicates)

Comment: mt_rand would create dupes from time to time like any

Comment: ah, see the thing is... i later want to use this number to select certain rows from the table in the database with PHP. If there are duplicates, php would get confused.

Comment: well then you should use the PRIMARY KEY like everyone is suggesting.

Comment: also that PRIMARY kEY can be used to link tables together later on as your project grows, so you can select from multiple tables in one query...

Comment: hey, I've decided to use the primary key with auto_increent. I just wanted to know, will this generate a completely random number like 624985673 and not something like 123456789? as far as i'm concerned, the auto_increment goes 01, 02, 03, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Try the `uniqid` function.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the rand function

[PHP manual: Rand()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.rand.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can do database stuff and you cannot generate an id?

random: `rand(1, 999999999)`

or from that insert i assume mysql: `mysql_insert_id()` - if you use ID's

Answer (score 0):

I cannot imagine why you would do this instead of using a `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`, but since you ask:

[`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/mt-rand) is the way to do.

## DO NOT USE `rand()` -- IT IS SLOW AND FLAWED

For proof of that concept, try the following:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
DEFINE('SQUARE_SIZE', 100);
$img = imagecreatetruecolor(SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE);

$ink = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);

for($i = 0, $max = pow(SQUARE_SIZE, 2); $i < $max; $i++) {
    imagesetpixel($img, mt_rand(1,SQUARE_SIZE), mt_rand(1,SQUARE_SIZE), $ink);
}

imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

You'll get pixel noise; if you change the `mt_rand` calls to `rand`, it will be a very obvious repeating pattern, and the same pattern every time.

### example is adapted from php manual comments for `mt_rand()`

Comment: ive tested that before and when the image is larger then 500,500 its not so random, baffling...

Comment: I don't see that at all.  Tried several sizes from 50x50 to 1024x1024 and `rand()` always shows a distinct pattern that repeats OFTEN, and `mt_rand()` is generally noise.

Comment: I take that back -- at small sizes, it is fairly random, not too different from `mt_rand`; however, patterns emerge at 115x115, and any larger and they become strikingly obvious.  By 200x200 the image is practically static if generate multiple times.  `mt_rand` does not suffer from this.

Comment: hey, I've decided to use the primary key with auto_increent. I just wanted to know, will this generate a completely random number like 624985673 and not something like 123456789? as far as i'm concerned, the auto_increment goes 01, 02, 03, etc etc