# PHP: Generating random string with both suffix and prefix as capital letters

Tags: php

Hie guys i want to create a random string of numbers where there is a fixed letter B at the beginning and a set of eight integers ending with any random letter, like for example B07224081A where A and the other numbers are random. This string should be unique. How can I do this?

Comment: This isn't a cakephp-specific question. Just good old PHP. Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php

Comment: Exactly.. Just google up how ti generate random alpha-numeric string and modify the script to your purpose!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$numbers = rand(10000000, 99999999);
$prefix = "B";
$sufix = $letters[rand(0, 25)];

$string = $prefix . $numbers . $sufix;
echo $string; // printed "B74099731P" in my case
```

The more characters - the greater chance to generate *unique* string.

I think that's much better method to use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) since it's based on miliseconds. Uniqueness of generated string is guaranteed.

Comment: In order to actually guarantee uniqueness, you'll need to keep track of the strings you've used and regenerate if you come up with a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
  $randomString = "B";
  for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    if ($i < 8) {
        $randomString.=rand(0,9);
    }  
    if ($i == 8) {
        $randomString.=chr(rand(65,90));
    }
  }
  echo $randomString;
```