# Random String PHP

Tags: php

I would like to do a random string but i'm using case function but it doesn't return any value when I echo it it returns no value at all.
Is there any wrong with my switch case function???

```
function assign_rand_value($id)
{
// accepts 1 - 36
  switch($id)
  {
    case "1":
     $rand_value = "a";
    break;
    case "2":
     $rand_value = "b";
    break;
    case "3":
     $rand_value = "c";
    break;
    case "4":
     $rand_value = "d";
    break;
    case "5":
     $rand_value = "e";
    break;
    case "6":
     $rand_value = "f";
    break;
    case "7":
     $rand_value = "g";
    break;
    case "8":
     $rand_value = "h";
    break;
    case "9":
     $rand_value = "i";
    break;
    case "10":
     $rand_value = "j";
    break;
    case "11":
     $rand_value = "k";
    break;
    case "12":
     $rand_value = "l";
    break;
    case "13":
     $rand_value = "m";
    break;
    case "14":
     $rand_value = "n";
    break;
    case "15":
     $rand_value = "o";
    break;
    case "16":
     $rand_value = "p";
    break;
    case "17":
     $rand_value = "q";
    break;
    case "18":
     $rand_value = "r";
    break;
    case "19":
     $rand_value = "s";
    break;
    case "20":
     $rand_value = "t";
    break;
    case "21":
     $rand_value = "u";
    break;
    case "22":
     $rand_value = "v";
    break;
    case "23":
     $rand_value = "w";
    break;
    case "24":
     $rand_value = "x";
    break;
    case "25":
     $rand_value = "y";
    break;
    case "26":
     $rand_value = "z";
    break;
    case "27":
     $rand_value = "0";
    break;
    case "28":
     $rand_value = "1";
    break;
    case "29":
     $rand_value = "2";
    break;
    case "30":
     $rand_value = "3";
    break;
    case "31":
     $rand_value = "4";
    break;
    case "32":
     $rand_value = "5";
    break;
    case "33":
     $rand_value = "6";
    break;
    case "34":
     $rand_value = "7";
    break;
    case "35":
     $rand_value = "8";
    break;
    case "36":
     $rand_value = "9";
    break;
  }
return $rand_value;
}
```

Is there any way for me to randomize with the following terms, despite the fact that it has already been randomized.

```
$additionalIDs = "testingjay1,testingjay2,testingjay3,testingjay4,testingjay5,testingjay6,testingjay7,testingjay8,testingjay9,testingjay10";
```

Comment: The link below has already answered this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php

Comment: @AJHacker, that's random char length also . I'm looking for array or something like rand();

Comment: What are you passing to the function? It accepts strings with number contents, not integers. Also, a switch is not the best way to do what you're doing; use an array or a string and pick the `$id`th element/character from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not enclose the values with quotation marks
should be:

```
case 1:
```

instead of:

```
case "1":
```

Also, I have written generate random string function - this might help you out:

```
function generate_random_string($length = 1){
    while ($length > 0){
        $whichof3options = rand (0,2);
        if ($whichof3options == 0){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(48,57)); //get random numerical chars
        }elseif ($whichof3options == 1){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(65,90)); //get random upper case alpha chars
        }elseif ($whichof3options == 2){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(97,122)); //get random lower case alpha chars
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        $length--;
    }
    if($output){
        return $output;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

What this basically does is create a random character using the chr fucntion and rand function, here are some references:

https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.rand.php

http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.chr.php

http://www.asciitable.com/

I have encapsulate the random character generator in a while loop so I can have control of the length of string to be generated.

Also, you can further improve this function if you want to have more control of the string that needs to be generated.

Here's an example. I have added some control in symbols, char case, etc

```
function generate_random_string($length = 1, $symbols = false, $lowercase = true, $uppercase = true, $numerical = true){

    while ($length > 0){

        $whichof3options = rand (0,3);
        
        if ($whichof3options == 0 && $numerical){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(48,57)); //get random numerical chars
        }elseif ($whichof3options == 1 && $uppercase){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(65,90)); //get random upper case alpha chars
        }elseif ($whichof3options == 2 && $lowercase){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(97,122)); //get random lower case alpha chars
        }elseif ($whichof3options == 3 && $symbols){
            $output = $output.chr(rand(33,47)); //get random symbols
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    
        $length--;
        
    }
    
    if($output){
        return $output;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```