# How to generate a unique token that is valid until it's manually reset, in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, token, reset

I need some way to generate a unique token that can be passed to a MySQL database, and stored there until it's manually reset. So it needs to be a random token that will be displayed to a user which should stay valid, but also have some function that can reset it - like a "reset key" link to automatically update, change, and then display the new token.

I was trying out this code, but it refreshes each time the page reloads:

```
global $wpdb;
global $user_login;
$token = uniqid();
$hashedtoken = md5($token);
$user = $user_login;

$wpdb->insert('wp_tokens', 
array('user' => $user, 'token' => $hashedtoken),
array('%s','%s')
);
echo $hashedtoken;
```

It might be obvious I am using Wordpress, if that matters. I'm not even sure PHP is the best option here.

**Edit:** My question was flagged as being similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php), and some cool people have notified that I need to query the database to check if the token exists for the user. However, no clue how to do these. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of always setting it, you need to check if a token already exists for that specific user first by querying the database.

Comment: Oh I see, that seems quite obvious now. So I can do that with a simple if -> then logic? Also, I can share the MySQL code I used to create the table if that matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a random string using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php)

Comment: Since you have MySQL at your disposal and you need some sort of unique string, why don't you use MySQL's `UUID()` function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
md5(uniqid($your_user_login, true))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what PHP says about using `uniqid()` for generating "random" strings:

> **Warning**
>   This function does not create random nor unpredictable strings. This
>   function must not be used for security purposes. Use a
>   cryptographically secure random function/generator and
>   cryptographically secure hash functions to create unpredictable secure
>   IDs.

A hash of a non-random string still isn't random.

Here's a link to two popular questions about generating a random string in PHP:

[How to create a random string using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php)

[PHP random string generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356289/php-random-string-generator)

Answer (score 0):

first you should at least use sha http://php.net/manual/de/function.sha1.php - no matter what you do with a token - script kiddies these days love to scan the web for pages that still uses md5 string length.

a fast hack would be to check to check if the token already exist in your database

Comment: Thanks, I did some googling and found this function:

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT token from wp_tokens where user = $user")

But I am unsure how to match that in my case. And then it would still need to either generate a new token or print the existing token. Any ideas how to achieve this?