# PHP Social Network - uploaded picture URL

Tags: php, image, url, random, profile

I want to know what strategy should i use to generate a random URL for my users uploaded pictures. I dont think str_shuffle is a good option, because it consumes a lot of memory ( am i wrong )? Please give me some tips for this kind of situation.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for a bijective formula - https://github.com/wdalmut/php-bijective

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a random string using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853813/how-to-create-a-random-string-using-php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$random = uniqid();
$url = "http://www.example.com/?v=$random";
echo $url;
```

The output will look something like: `http://www.example.com/?v=4b3403665fea8`

You would then save `$random` in a database for future use ;)

Comment: not my dv, but I think you meant `uniqid()` and not `unique()`.

Comment: only when I'm 100% sure of my shot ;-)

Comment: *Hm....*, looking at the OP's question again, your answer won't work and I'll tell you why. They would need to have existing ids/images to match what `uniqid()` generates, so I think their best bet would be to use a database and run a random function from a SELECT. That's probably why you got the downvote. Read the question again. I had to remove my upvote, sorry (and that isn't my downvote you know).

Comment: @Fred-ii- Alright, so If I saved `$random` in a database, would that then be sufficient? I believe uniqid() is unique to the millisecond and will stay unique for many centuries to come, though I could be mistaken in my understanding.