# Dealing with large amount of data in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So i have something like a auction and for each deal or that auction i have to generate random identifier code and assign to user.
So i came up with something like this for db storage `{1:XKF3325A|ADSTD2351;7:ZARASR23;12:3290OASJX}` - so what i have there is user id : random code and some user can have several random codes seperated by |.

My question is what type of storing i should use for my db? The codes i generate for users might be over 2k-3k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what if they are over 3k? MySQL can deal with huge stuff, don't worry. Just use two tables, like:

```
Users
 - id
 - other info..

Identifiers
 - random_str
 - foreign key to user
```

Then you can fetch identifiers for an id, fetch the user that an identifier belongs to, etc

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're asking the wrong question. You simply shouldn't be dealing with identifiers of this size. The answer is to deal with smaller identifiers by using a better identifier generation algorithm. Your table indexes will thank you.

So the question you should be asking is: **How do I create short but unique identifiers?** The answer is as follows:

You should use a cryptographically secure hash algorithm (eg. [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)) to generate your identifier, or just use a UUID implementation to do this. PHP has a UUID implementation called [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) (might have to be compiled in), so there's really no need to roll your own. Both methods give you an ID that is way shorter than what you're using, and both can "guarantee" uniqueness across a huge sample size (and more effectively than your algorithm). And when I say shorter, I'm talking anywhere between 16-64 bytes at most (SHA-1 generates 40byte hashes).

If you go the SHA-1 hash route, the methodology would be to hash some random (but unique-to-the-user input), like `sha1(timestamp+username+itemname+randomseed)`. You can also make use of `uniqid` here (see the comments in the PHP documentation for the function) and do: `sha1(uniqid())`. Make sure to read the notes about `uniqid()` to see the caveats about generating many ids per second.

Comment: In later stage i need to present the code for each user and that's why i do only 10 chars with caps and numbers. Something like sha1 would produce terrible string for user to read.

Comment: If your code for a user might be 2k to 3k then it's going to be a whole lot worse than a sha1() hash for a user to read!  Other suggestions are available at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php

Comment: I really don't see how a SHA-1 hash is any worse than the example you've provided. You could always perform some symmetric translation for easier display (separate each 8 chars with '-'), if you were concerned, but "random string of characters" is always going to look like "random string of characters".

Comment: Yobo the 2k to 3k is not for 1 user ofcourse each user gets so many records as it's supposed to get eg. 1-5 depending on specific situation.

@Loren Segal so to recap you want me to use 40 char string and process it for display instead of 10 char string that don't need to be processed. I'm sorry if i don't get your idea maybe i got it totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First - see Loren Segal's answer for some good ideas.

Second - why would you use anything random to ensure uniqueness?  Random values don't guarantee uniquness -- even if they can make it very unlikely that you'll have a collision.

In most every case, relational databases can solve your problem without any tricks.  Indexes and composite keys are designed to solve this kind of problem efficiently.

If you need a single value to uniquely identify something, look into the uniquid stuff that Loren mentioned.