# Gravity Forms custom validation filter

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a function that processes sales via a third-party service, processes the result and returns an array with the Status "Success" or "Invalid." This sales call is made using the gform_after_submission hook applied to the specific form.

What I need to do is store the "Success" or "Invalid" result in the array as a variable that I can later pass to a function to validate or invalidate the credit card field, using gform_validation hook.

I'm declaring the variable in a function, like so:

```
function foo { 
...code to sell product through API...

$status = $checkoutShoppingCartRequest['Result']['Status'];
}
```

When I print the variable $status within the function, it is showing either Success or Invalid like it should.

Here is other function where I need to use this variable, passed to gform_validation, which fails every time regardless of Success or Invalid result:

```
function MBvalidate( $validation_result ) {
$form = $validation_result['form'];
if ( $status !== "Success") {
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;
    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->id == '34' ) {
            $field->failed_validation = true;
            $field->validation_message = 'Your credit card could not be processed.';
            break;
        }
    }
}
//Assign modified $form object back to the validation result
$validation_result['form'] = $form;
return $validation_result;

}

add_filter( 'gform_validation_47', 'MBvalidate' );
```

I have tried passing the variable a number of different ways, via globals and sessions, etc.

I am new to GF development so I am sure I'm missing something. I'd appreciate any direction.

Comment: Where did you pass? `$status` variable in a callback function ? have you `var_dump($validation_result)` variable ?

Comment: I am assuming you made the variable global by adding `global` keyword inside `MBvalidate()` function i.e. `global $status ` , am I correct? Also you will have to put `global` keyword inside `foo()` function as well

Answer (score 1):

The `gform_after_submission` action hook runs *after* `gform_validation`.

Anyway, assuming you can [find a hook](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/category/hooks/) that runs earlier, what I would do is store a unique variable for each submitted form using the [Transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)'s `set_transient()` and `get_transient()` functions. For example you can create a hidden field in every form which you populate with a [random ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php). Use this random ID as a key to store and retrieve the Success/Invalid result.

Answer (score 0):

`$status` here is a local variable which has never been defined before you try to use it in if-condition. So, it's always `null`.
Maybe you missed

```
$status = $validation_result['Result']['Status'];
```

or something like this before checking the condition.