# Assigning unique serial key to each to user

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, serialization, database-design

I have a system, survey form that I have developed.
my problem is **how do I Insert or assign the serial key value to the survey table in the database?**

I have to two tables one to store the survey answers and the other table that  stores the serial keys. After the user fills in the survey/questionnaire, how can I then assign a serial key to each completed survey(in the database), and then display to the user the assigned serial key.

Also How can I make sure that Once a specific serial key is assigned, it won't be assigned again.

I am using php and Jquery mobile and mysql to develope the system

I really need help.

Comment: Please show the code that you may have tried.

Comment: There are functions which do this in several languages. eg. http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Don’t know. That’s up to you to decide. We’re not here to architect your system.

Comment: I tried to use a trigger, but it does not work

Comment: INSERT INTO `hiv_survey_answers`(`serialkey`)
SELECT `user_id`, `serialkey` FROM `serialkeys`

Comment: What's wrong with `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a UUID. There are functions to create these in several languages:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html
etc...

Comment: Agree with Matthew, this is easiest way but if you want to create your own function for this you can check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php