# Php and bash together to generate keys

Tags: php, bash, nginx, http-live-streaming

I have this bash file which generates key and expire time :

```
#!/bin/bash
get_customer_url() {
  local IP=${1:-127.0.0.1}
  local SECRET=${2:-VERY_COOL_SECRET}
  local EXPIRES="$(date -d "today + 30 minutes" +%s)";
  local token="$(echo -n "${EXPIRES} VERY_COOL_SECRET" | openssl md5 -binary | openssl base64 | tr +/ -_ | tr -d =)"
  echo "/${token}/${EXPIRES}/"
}
get_customer_url
```

and i call it via php like this

```
<?php $output = shell_exec('sh generate-keys-hls.sh'); echo "$output";?>
```

it works fine , it generates something like this

```
/G8INKLc3VfDMYtQT2NTU-w/1530222035/
```

my problem is i want to put another php result in the some line like this

```
<?php $output = shell_exec('sh generate-keys-hls.sh'); echo "$output";?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'file', true)?>
```

currently its printing the result in two lines i need it to be one just one line instead of this

```
/G8INKLc3VfDMYtQT2NTU-w/1530222035/ 
file.mp4.m3u8
```

i want it to be like this

```
/G8INKLc3VfDMYtQT2NTU-w/1530222035/file.mp4.m3u8
```

without white spaces or multiple lines !

Comment: Why all of this when you can do it all in PHP alone? See also [generate random key in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php).

Comment: @LioraHaydont Why would that help? `echo` doesn't add a newline by itself.

Comment: @Barmar ah, I forgot about that, sorry

Comment: I don't know how to convert the bash script to php , if someone can convert it to me i would very appreciate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the whitespace around the result of `shell_exec()`.

```
echo trim($output);
```