# Inserting random characters to MYSQL Database

Tags: mysql, random

I want to add 100 entry to users table numbers field, random characters length is 10, all entry should be unique as well. How can i achieve this using MYSQL query code ?

Or do i need to use PHP ?

Help me with code snippets please. Thanks.

Comment: you want to update exist rows ?  or insert new rows ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in mysql u can do like :

```
insert into table ( SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) , field2 , field3) , ( SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) , field2 , field3) , .........
```

..............

in php see this 2 links :

[Short unique id in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307486/short-unique-id-in-php/307773#307773)

[What is the best way to generate a random key within PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637278/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-a-random-key-within-php)

Comment: hello, i want to add 100 entry once. How can i achieve ? I have to use insert instead of update right ?

Comment: hi haim, how to insert 100 rows by just one query ?

Comment: i show the example in my answer with comma u can separated 100 insert

Answer (score 8):

That may create duplicates and it's too long. This is 10 char long:

```
UPDATE users SET numbers = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10)
```

However, you could still get duplicate values.

So you could put a unique restraint on your column. Then try the update. If there are duplicates, you will get an error. Then just try again. You only have 100 entries, so it's probably fine.

Is this for passwords?

If so, I'd recommend encrypting the value. Of course you then have the problem of not knowing what the value is. So you could create a temporary table, insert the random values in there. Then encrypt the values as they are inserted from the temp table into the real table. You can then use the temp table for reference (giving the users their passwords, etc). Hope that helps.

Comment: I do realize this answer is 6 years old, but still storing the plain text password even if in a separate "temp" table/column is just defeating the purpose of hashing and is a security hole. Passwords should be **irretrievable** whatsoever. And about "*giving the users their passwords*" -- Passwords should never be "given", and rather they should be entered by the end user.

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE TABLE users SET number_field = MD5(RAND());
```

Comment: If rand returns the same number twice, wouldn't that create a violation of the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: will only work in mysql, in other DBMS you would need to truncate the md5

Comment: hi, i want to add 100 entry by once ? How can i ?

Comment: Hi @sum1stolemyname you are right. my mistake. A function counting from 1 to 100 will be better. But anyway just wanted to point a direction for solution.

Comment: @spotlightsnap: are you talking about 'entry' (which I read as add to field for one user or 'row', as in : add 100 users with a 10-char number_field for each???

Comment: hi lexu, it's like this, i have table name called users, at users table, there's field name called numbers, i want to generate 100 row and insert into that users table numbers field. Currently the above code generate only 1 row at a time. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate an unique random number. Over time, the randomness will generate a number already stored. You need to make a "quasi-random" number, meaning that it's a number based on another data, but it just looks random. You can use the primary key on the table as the base number to generate the "fake-random" number

```
INSERT INTO myTable(primaryKey,quasiRandom) 
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(primaryKey),0)+1, CAST(CONCAT(IFNULL(MAX(primaryKey),0)+1,CHAR(FLOOR(RAND()*26)+65),FLOOR(100+RAND()*(500-100)))
 AS CHAR(10)) AS quasiRandom FROM myTable
```