# Generate unused license plate

Tags: php, mysql, logic

For a multiplayer game I'm working on, I need to be able to create vehicles for players. Each vehicle needs to have an entirely unique license plate.

The vehicles details are stored in a MySQL table called "vehicles" and the license plate is in the "plate" column. I want to generate a random license plate (three alphanumeric characters, followed by a space, followed by three more alphanumeric characters) that doesn't match any in the table.

I'm not sure how to do it, though. I thought about using a while loop and just constantly regenerating a new plate until a SELECT query for that plate returns 0 rows but that just seems inefficient - is there a better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL - Best way to create unique random string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893257/php-mysql-best-way-to-create-unique-random-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should be fine. There are over 2 billion possible license plates in that scheme, and the database will only have a few thousand. So the chance of repeating a plate number will be very tiny. The first query will almost always confirm that the plate number is unique, and if not the second one will. If you ever had to do 3 queries, I would be very, very surprised.

The number of possible license plates is: 36<sup>6</sup> = 2,176,782,336

Comment: I was always warned about using while loops to generate unique random results but I suppose if there are 2+ billion combinations then the chances are **very** slim. Can I ask how you calculated the total number of combinations?

Comment: Updated answer with the calculation.

Comment: @James Do make sure that your queries are atomical here. If you first `SELECT` then `INSERT`, you run a (albeit it low) chance of a race condition in which you generate identical plates twice. Use a UNIQUE constraint on the column, `INSERT` and handle the possible error to avoid this case.

Comment: @Barmar I planned to use 7-character license plates in order for better realism which gives me 78 billion combinations, much more than I thought!

Comment: @deceze What is a race condition? I'm unsure how I could generate identical plates twice if I check that it doesn't exist before inserting :P

Comment: A race condition is a failure that results from timing of independent processes. E.g. You generate a plate number and do a SELECT to see if it's available. At the same time, another process generates and tests the same plate number.  When they each do their inserts, you end up with a duplicate.