# Generate alphanumeric ID with PHP

Tags: php

I want to generate some sort of ID similar to the way that Google generates URLs for their classroom service.

For example:
`https://classroom.google.com/u/0/c/MTg1MKIwNTk4`

I want to be able to generate the `MTg1MKIwNTk4` part.

It doesn't have to be cryptographically secure or anything like that, it is just being used for a URL.

How can this be done with PHP (+MySQL)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you ask how make string of random chars?

Comment: What have you done so far ? I would suggest you to  [do a search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=php+generate+random+string+mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL - Best way to create unique random string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893257/php-mysql-best-way-to-create-unique-random-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$charset = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$str = '';
$length = strlen($charset);
$count = 12;
while ($count--) {
    $str .= $charset[mt_rand(0, $length-1)];
}
echo $str;
```

If you use PHP7, you can use `random_int` instead of `mt_rand` to get even better random numbers. (Proposed by @zaph in the comments).

And, of course, if you want to have random strings that are more easy to copy by hand (e.g. if you print your URLs), then you could omit some of the characters that could be ambiguous (like 'l' or '0') - (again proposed by @zaph in the comments)

Comment: It is better to use the [Base58](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base58) character set, it does not have ambitious characters, the letters omitted are: 0 (zero), O (capital o), I (capital i) and l (lower case L) as well as the non-alphanumeric characters + (plus) and / (slash).

Comment: It is better to use `random_int` than `mt_rand`.

Comment: If you use PHP7, then this should be the option. I'll add it to my answer, thanks @zaph

Answer (score 0):

Use [md5()](http://php.net/md5) in combination with .htaccess(Apache)/web.config(IIS) to get it.

You'll get an alphanumeric 32-char-length string. Cut it using [substr()](http://php.net/substr)

Example:

`md5('helloworld')` generate *fc5e038d38a57032085441e7fe7010b0*

`substr(md5('helloworld'),0,10)` generates *fc5e038d38*

Comment: This solution is nice and short, but is not yet the solution requested by the OP, because the string can only contain a small subset of characters.

Comment: You're right @JoachimSchirrmacher Anyway , this would work when it is not mandatory the string mixes upper and lower chars. Thank you for the correction anyway.

Comment: Where does it say OP only wants a small subset of chars? It only stipulates alpha numeric chars. I don't see why this answer is downvoted.

Comment: I don't know either. And, actually, the OP didn't say he wanted a subset, but the answer is restricted to do so, since `md5()` uses only hex digits.