# PHP Unique random string generator

Tags: php, laravel, random

How to make a random string unique to the string in the column below?

[image]

```
<?php
$n=10;
function getName($n) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1);
        $randomString .= $characters[$index];
    }

    return $randomString;
}

echo getName($n);
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP/MySQL - Best way to create unique random string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893257/php-mysql-best-way-to-create-unique-random-string)

Comment: Is `string` column already defined as unique?

Comment: Yes, But sometimes it will randomize the already existing string causing an error when saving.

Comment: You mean you randomize the random string? Not sure I know what you mean.. whats the error?

Comment: If I want to randomize one number from "1,2,3", But there is already a row with the value 2 in the "String" column, the random value must be either 1 or 3.

Comment: That is unique, not random.. What error are you receiving? Value already exists?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $n = 10;
    function getName($n) {
        $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1);
            $randomString .= $characters[$index];
        }
        return $randomString;
    }
    function getUniqueString($length, $dbConnection){
        $string = getName($length);
        $count  = $dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE string='$string')")->num_rows;
        while($count != 0){
            $string = getName($length);
            $count  = $dbConnection->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE string='$string')")->num_rows;
        }
        return $string;
    }

    echo getUniqueString($n, $dbConnection);
?>
```

Comment: If the table name is "test', how should I add the table name?

Comment: Replace `TABLE_NAME` with what your actual table name is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() or random_bytes() PHP fonction to generate random strings.

You can also rely on MySQL to generate uniq IDs :

```
INSERT INTO mytable (alphaID) VALUES (REPLACE( UUID(), '-', '' ));
```