# How to create one property based in another property of the same document?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, constructor, properties

I have a simple document that has its ID:

```
 /**
     * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="increment")
     * @Serializer\Since("2.0")
     */
    protected $id;
```

and a property **code**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 */
protected $code;
```

I want that the code be generated based in the ID. So I am planning to define it in the constructor

```
  public function __construct()
{
$this->code = (string)$this->id.(string)rand(0,1000);
}
```

My question is, as both are defined in the same php class, there would be any risk to define one based in another?

Any risk of the **code** ask for the **id** before it was defined? Or there is any better way of doing such thing?

Comment: is it correct that you dont want to save the code property in database and have it only for serialized object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ID will be null when you create the object. To create code property you should set it after the persist. Something like this:

```
 $dm = $this->get('doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager');

 $item = new Item();
 $item->setSomeValue($someValue);
 $dm->persist($item);
 $dm->flush();

 $item->setCode($item->getId());
 $dm->persist($item);
 $dm->flush();
```

As you can imagine, this is not a good practice and you should avoid it. **Generate values from database ID it is not a good idea** too. I recommend you to use functions like [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/es/function.uniqid.php) to do the workaround. Uniqid is safer, faster and cleaner.

Comment: While I agree it's better to generate your own ids, I would not recommend using uniqid() for it. A better option would be UUID, which can easily be generated by libraries like ramsey/uuid.

Comment: I used the function gen_uuid() described in this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307486/short-unique-id-in-php/307773

Answer (score 0):

if you just want the serialized obj to be like:

```
{
 id:123,
 code:123
}
```

u can just add a getter function and it will be included in serialized result

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 */
protected $code;

public function getCode(){
   return $this->getId();
}
```

if this does not work automagicaly (should) you can use annotations for serializer:

```
/**
 * @JMS\Expose
 * @JMS\Accessor(getter="getCode") 
 */
private $code;
```

if you want to persist the code property you can do it like Vangoso, but it does not realy make sense storing the same information twice